# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.RNTimePickerAndroid.dismiss')

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

Am facing this issue, while am passing the value prop as a new Date() to DateTimePicker, this was working fine before a week back.

<DateTimePicker testID="dateTimePicker" // value={current ? current.actualTime : new Date()} value={new Date()} mode={'time'} is24Hour={false} display="default" onChange={(e, d) => { if (d) { const hours = d.getHours().toString().length > 1 ? d.getHours() : '0' + d.getHours(); const minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length > 1 ? d.getMinutes() : '0' + d.getMinutes(); onChangeTime(hours + ":" + minutes, d); } }} />

"react-native": "0.63.2",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Try to install the latest debug build from the android studio, this error will be gone.
just the matter of bundle cache,